# visual studio startup projects dropdown not showing one of projects

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio startup projects dropdown not showing one of the projects.

[image: DropDown image]

The project is in the solution. In Solution Explorer, I can right click to the project and select "Set as StartUp Project".

I just want to see it in startup projects dropdown.

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.
There are web projects and console projects in solution.

Comment: You need to add more information. What are the project types? Which visual studio version are you using?

Comment: Happens to me too. A .NET Framework Web API project is missing from the list, but I can still right-click the project and set it as the startup.

Comment: The same thing happened to me after installing VS 2022 RC3. It also broke the VS 2019.

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but looks like there is currently no fix to this issue and based on the questions found on VS Development Community this issue has been raised but closed as low priority.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/startup-projects-list-in-the-toolbar-doesnt-show-a/280186

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/projects-missing-from-startup-project-dropdown/397420

In my case, startup dropdown seems to only show dotnet core projects and console projects (and randomly some library projects).

As @Keith has mentioned above a work around is to right-click desired project and set   selected project as startup. That project will then be actively selected in the startup dropdown.

Comment: The same thing for 2019 and 2022. The problem seemingly started after some upgrade of 2019. The extension fixes the issue. You can also use Customize buttons command to remove the broken dropdown, just to avoid having two of them.

Comment: I have VS 2022 and I had two clones of the same project, where one had dropdown and second didn't. It doesn't seem to be type of project that influences this behavior but some action that either I did or VS on its own. Deleting .vs directory fixed it for me

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with VS 2022.
To fix it, (like many other issues with VS) I closed Visual Studio and deleted the .vs file in the project folder (should be in the same folder as the .sln file). Note that all open files in Visual Studio will be closed.

[image: .vs file]

Answer (score 2):

An answer in [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/startup-projects-list-in-the-toolbar-doesnt-show-a/280186) thread points to the [SwitchStartupProject](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProject) extension. It works well to show and start all projects in the solution and replaces the regular Startup Project drop-down.